# Physics Problem: Entropy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

A parachutist having the weigh of $88~\rm kg$ falls vertically from a height of $460~\rm m$ at a constant speed. Calculate the increase in entropy produced by the parachutist, assuming that the air temperature is $21 ~^\circ \mathrm C.$

$$\Delta S = \frac{Q}{T}= \frac{W}{T} = \frac{mgh}{T}$$

So far I found this is the correct answer, but I don't really understand why the heat is equal to the work made by the air. Also, if it is correct, how could the work equal to $mgh\,?$

Comment: Good example of a "homework like question" that actually follows the policy of the site well (as I interpret it). You are not asking for the answer, but for help with a specific principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parachutists starts out with a certain amount of potential energy, $mgh$. This energy needs to be dissipated before she reaches the ground - and this is done by doing work against the air (in essence, stationary air is put into motion by the parachute, and so the potential energy of the parachutist is turned into kinetic energy of the air; from there, it dissipates into "general thermal motion" of the air molecules - which we call "heat").

Comment: So I have to consider it as a conservative energy, where all the potential energy is supposed to be converted into the kinetic energy of the air, which consequently it produces heat, right?

Comment: Yes - conservation of energy